# Height problems

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem regarding height. I have a footer following the code bellow:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class='wrap'>
        <div class=principal></div>
        <div class='clear'></div>
        <footer><img alt='Logotype' /></footer>
    </div>      
</body>
</html>


html,body{
    height:100%;
};

.wrap{
    height:auto!important;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}

footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
}
```

*There's another way that is putting margin: 0 auto -50px in the .wrap, and put footer outside the wrap.*

I need the .principal to have 100% of the height when there's not so much content because I have a component that inject in the .principal a `<div style='height:100%>insert text and graphics/charts here</div>`.

See examples bellow to understand better:

**Image 1:**

[Content 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLRlj.png)

I need the content (.principal) to have 100% of the height because of the component. I have a menu that opens when clicked, and that should have the size of the content (.principal), I want the footer in the bottom of the page.

**Image 2:**

[Scrolling Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrXi3.png)

If there's more content (due to text or something) I want a scroll and the footer disappear, and the header fixed.

**Image 3:**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/294ic.png)

At the bottom of the scroll, it should appear the footer. When the menu is open the menu should have the height of the size of the displayed content (in this case the height = window-height-footer).

So there's a way that an element can have 100% of the height, but when there's a lot of content it's expands?

**Obstacles:**

- I can't use flexbox model because of IE8+(needed compatibility).
- I can't use height: calc because of Safari and IE.
- I can't put everything in height:100% because of footer.
- I can't put images because of reputation.

Comment: Just curious, what does OBS stand for?

Comment: Never mind, it's "Note" in Portuguese.  Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

Demo: 
http://www.cssreset.com/demos/layouts/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

It's a simple script which makes your footer stick to the bottom of the page but once you add more content it wil go down with it. (demo)

This is an example using this script:
(I also added a fixed navigation)
html:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        <div id="nav"></div>
        <div id="content_push" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;"></div> <!-- makes sure the first content doesn't dissapear beneeth the nav>
    </div><!-- #header -->

    <div id="content">
        Copy this to add content<br><br><br><br>
        Copy this to add content<br><br><br><br>
        Copy this to add content<br><br><br><br>
        Copy this to add content<br><br><br><br>
    </div><!-- #content -->

    <div id="footer">
    </div><!-- #footer -->

</div><!-- #wrapper -->
```

css:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    background:#ededed;
    padding:0px;

}
#nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: green;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    background:#ffab62;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Try it out: https://jsfiddle.net/krjoqfru/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correctly. You wan't sticky footer?

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
#wrap { min-height: 100%; height: auto !important; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto -50px; }
#footer, #push { margin: 0 auto; height: 50px; }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    your content goes here
    <div id="push"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Your footer</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; } 
body { height:100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; }
header { height: 50px; width: 100%; position: fixed; }
.principal { min-height: 100%; width: 100%; }
footer { height:50px; width:100%; }
```

```html
<header style="background: green;"></header>
<div class='principal' style="background: red;"></div> 
<footer style="background: blue;"></footer>
```