# Height 100% and css issue with footer

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a script and in some pages there isn't enough content.In this case I want the page to cover 100% of the browser and put the footer at the bottom.I tried many codes and nothing seems to work I ended up by having a code like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div id=nav>
NAV
</div>
<div id=core>
    <div id=content>
        <div id=tophea>
           TOP Content
        </div>
        <div id=msgs>
       MSG Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    Footer
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css like this :

```
#container{
  height:100%
}
#nav{
  height:55px;
}
#core{
  height:100%
}
#content{
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/k8k7o36b/

Any help will be appreciate. I'll be more than thankful if you add small explanation so I can understand what were I doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Not entirely sure what your'e asking, but if you want your content to take up the fullscreen set the `height` to `100vh`.

Comment: You can put the footer outside of the container with position absolute and bottom 0, then you add a margin-bottom to the container in the height of the footer, but the footer will always stay on bottom even if the container height is > 100%, the margin ensures you can see all the content when scrolling.

Comment: You have `class="container"` but the CSS selector `#container` which is for IDs (starts with `#` instead of `.`) not classes. Percentage height requires a parent to have a height set. This will continue up the DOM tree if the parent height is also a percentage. Because of this you need to set `height: 100%;` on `html` and `body` so that `.container` can inherit the window height properly. In the end you're looking for a [Sticky Footer](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) solution.

Comment: @Conor I've tried this before but the issue with that is that the footer isn't shown at the bottom because the height will be 100vh + the height of the nav which is 55px.

Comment: I'll post a solution to help with that.

Comment: I have seen this question before, this answer might help you achieve this...  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30470081/3103229

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container{
  height:100%
}
#nav{
  height:55px;
}
#core{
  height:100%
}
#content{
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
#footer {
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id=nav>
    NAV
    </div>
    <div id=core>
        <div id=content>
            <div id=tophea>
               TOP Content
            </div>
            <div id=msgs>
           MSG Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer id="footer">
        Footer
        </footer>
      </div>
</div>
```

This should do it. I changed `div` to a `footer` and added some styling to the `#footer` id so that it has a `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;`. You can look into what position: absolute does [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

Edit: Obviously, you can adjust the height of the footer however you want, I just set it to 100px and background-color orange so that we can see it better.

Comment: The footer should be at the bottom, and instead the content div is the one who should take all the space.

Comment: Also if there is enough content the footer will stick and be over the content thing that I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `flexbox`:

- Note you need to use `100%` on *html and body*  and also your `footer` element at the same level of *nav and core*

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  background: orange;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#nav {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 55px;
}
#core {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id=nav>
    NAV
  </div>
  <div id=core>
    <div id=content>
      <div id=tophea>
        TOP Content
      </div>
      <div id=msgs>
        MSG Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Footer <br> footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DaniPc is it compatible with most browsers ?

Comment: @YassineBelatar most of all except IE9 or below http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox .... you may need some vendor prefixes for older browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flex layout and set the main content area to `flex-grow: 1` so it will consume all of the available space between your nav and footer, and that will push the footer to the bottom of the page when there isn't enough content.

```css
body,
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container,
#core {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#core,
#content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id=nav>
    NAV
  </div>
  <div id=core>
    <div id=content>
      <div id=tophea>
        TOP Content
      </div>
      <div id=msgs>
        MSG Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use calculations in css to help with this.

```
#core {
    height: (100vh - 55px)
}
```

100vh is 100% of the viewport, while he 55px is the height of the footer. Add any other elements to the calculation if you give them a height also e.g.

```
#header{
    height: 45px
}
#core {
    height: (100vh - 100px)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body,#container{
  height:100%
}
#nav{
  height:55px;
}
#core{
  height:100%
}
#content{
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
#footer{
  position:absolute;bottom:0;
  right:0;left:0
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id=nav>
    NAV
    </div>
    <div id=core>
        <div id=content>
            <div id=tophea>
               TOP Content
            </div>
            <div id=msgs>
           MSG Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        Footer
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add these classes

```
html,body{
  height:100%
}

#footer{
  position:absolute;bottom:0;
  right:0;left:0
}
```

Comment: The footer shouldn't be in fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic `flexbox` solution.

`flex-grow: 1;` tells `main` to fill the remaining space. This also has the benefit of not having to set a specific height on your footer.

### [Flexbox Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

- Chrome 21+
- Firefox 28+
- IE 10+
- Edge
- Safari 6.1+

****Some might support the 2012 syntax or require a prefix like `-webkit-`***

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}
header {
  background-color: indianred;
}
main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
footer {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<main>
  Content
</main>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: your solution seems to be working but I am facing an issue I can't set the height of div inside the flex main: https://jsfiddle.net/z6jyku03/ content should be 100% height as the same height as parent.

Comment: Are you trying to create a sidebar or something? Is that why the inner element has to be as tall as the parent?

Comment: No, It's a normal div with different background which should be 100%

Comment: I was just curios as to why you need it to be 100% of the parent. Anyways, just set `<main>` to `display: flex;`, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6jyku03/1/).

Comment: It's a content box whith which background which is set to be at the same height of main. and display:flex; doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure how setting `main` to `display: flex;` doesn't work for. You asked for the `div` within `main` to be `100%` the height of `main` and **[it is in this example](https://jsfiddle.net/z6jyku03/1/)**. Could you please be more specific? Also, this an issue not related to the question, which had to do with footer placement.